# How to capture n lines above a regex match in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string like this :

```
[01112017 110228 359][1][INFO]> Get Cash Unit Info
[01112017 110228 400][1][INFO]> ---Cash Unit Info Ready True
[01112017 110228 698][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 0 Value 01  REJC  ---  0000  0000  0004  000    OK
[01112017 110228 699][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 1 Value 02  RETR  ---  0000  0000  0000  000    OK
[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 2 Value 03  BILL  LKR  5000  1000  0999  001    OK
[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 3 Value 04  BILL  LKR  1000  2000  1999  001    OK
[01112017 110228 701][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 4 Value 05  BILL  LKR  0500  2000  1999  001    OK
[01112017 110228 702][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 5 Value 06  BILL  LKR  0100  2000  1999  001    OK
[01112017 110244 760][1][INFO]> ======================================
[01112017 110244 760][1][INFO]> TTU Back Panel Log Out
```

I would like to capture 5 lines above the string "TTU Back Panel Log Out".

I have already tried the regex **((.*\n){5})TTU Back Panel Log Out** and it outputs 0 matches

Any help would be appreciated. Note: with **Python3** using library **re**

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: does every `TTU Back Panel Log Out` message come after `======================================` message?

Comment: above = re.findall(r'((.*\n){5})TTU Back Panel Log Out',stringtosearch,re.DOTALL)

Comment: Just loop through the lines individually, and keep a stack of the last five lines, until you encounter the relevant line. Easier to read, and works just as well.

Comment: yes @AzatIbrakov

Comment: then iterate through lines and stop when line with `======================================` is reached, no regexp needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your string is called `s`):

```
re.findall('(.*)(?:.*\n){5}.*TTU Back Panel Log Out', s)
```

which returns:

```
['[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 2 Value 03  BILL  LKR  5000  1000  0999  001    OK']
```

`(?:.*\n){5}` is a *non-capturing* group (due to the `?:`), but searches for any characters occuring before a new line 5 times. The `(.*)` preceding it is the group you're capturing

Comment: cool !. How about matching all 5 lines above from the target string?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. This should work: `re.findall('((?:.*\n){5}).*TTU Back Panel Log Out', s)`

Answer (score 2):

In your regexp, you are assuming that your target line starts with your pattern, which is not the case.

Although, I believe you could achieve a better and more readable solution by looping through your lines and finding your pattern with `in`.

```
def find_lines_before_pattern(pattern, n, text):
    lines = text.splitlines()

    for lineno, line in enumerate(lines):
        if pattern in line:
            first_line = max(lineno - n, 0)
            break
    else:
        # Define your behaviour if the pattern is not found
        raise ValueError('Pattern not found')

    return lines[first_line: lineno]

text = """
some
lines
before
your
pattern
[01112017 110244 760][1][INFO]> TTU Back Panel Log Out
"""

find_lines_before_pattern('TTU Back Panel Log Out', 5, text)
# output: ['some', 'lines', 'before', 'your', 'pattern']
```

Answer (score 0):

The sixth line doesn't start with your target string `TTU Back Panel` - there's other text. So you need `.*?` before it:

```
>>> text = '''[01112017 110228 359][1][INFO]> Get Cash Unit Info
[01112017 110228 400][1][INFO]> ---Cash Unit Info Ready True''' # etc.
>>> re.search('([^\n]*\n){5}.*?TTU Back Panel', text)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(312, 829), match='[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern :

```
import re
pattern = r'((.*\n){5})\[\d.+\]\[1\]\[INFO\]\> TTU Back Panel Log Out'

print(re.findall(pattern,text))
```

output:

```
[('[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 2 Value 03  BILL  LKR  5000  1000  0999  001    OK\n[01112017 110228 700][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 3 Value 04  BILL  LKR  1000  2000  1999  001    OK\n[01112017 110228 701][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 4 Value 05  BILL  LKR  0500  2000  1999  001    OK\n[01112017 110228 702][1][INFO]> Cash Unit Info - 5 Value 06  BILL  LKR  0100  2000  1999  001    OK\n[01112017 110244 760][1][INFO]> ======================================\n', '[01112017 110244 760][1][INFO]> ======================================\n')]
```

> Regex information :

The following RegEx tests for a variable amount of lines before the `[\d.+\]\[1\]\[INFO\]\> TTU Back Panel Log Out`  line .

1. `(.*\n)` tests for a string ending with `\n`, a newline.
2. `{5}` quantifies
   this 5 times.
3. `()` around that makes sure all lines come in one
   capture group.
4. `[\d.+\]\[1\]\[INFO\]\> TTU Back Panel Log Out` is the string that the text has to end with.